# How to setup custom domain for FoxIDs control web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, idp, foxids

I would like to use my own custom domain for [FoxIDs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs) control web app. Is there a way how to setup it, will it be enough to add it to Azure Web App/Custom domains section?
Should I do anything else in FoxIDs control settings?

There is information about [custom domains](https://www.foxids.com/docs/custom-domain) per Tenant but nothing I found about about control Web App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a [custom primary domain](https://www.foxids.com/docs/deployment#custom-primary-domains) for your FoxIDs Control site.

I usually configure both custom primary domains (on the FoxIDs site and the FoxIDs control site) and a custom domain for the `main` tenant in FoxIDs.